# Why did bitcoin rise so sharply in the last week?

Tags: market

Answers a plenty!

Because it broke $1b market cap?

Because it was on many financial paper front pages?

Because all the usual suspects (forex watchers) saw a bubble coming?

Comment: This question is likely to invite speculation and discussion. For that reason, I'm voting to close it.

Answer (score 1):

A large number of people in certain countries in Europe have begun using BTC as a place to shelter some of their financial holdings from government seizure.

Comment: Not that I necessarily disagree, but can you cite this claim?

Comment: Aren't those people playing with fire anyway given the wild fluctuation we might reasonably expect in the future?  I realize govt seizure is worse, but aren't there less risky places to shelter their funds?